# Подстановка данных из JSON в HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

С помощью Ajax-запроса приходят данные в формате JSON:

```
[
    "status": 1
    "city": [
        "москва", "санкт-петербург"
    ]
]
```

Вот таким образом я получаю данные от сервера:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: msg,
    success: function(html) {
        var res = JSON.parse(html);
        $('#cities h5').text("Города куда было продано оборудование:");
        $('#cities span').text(res.city);
    }
});
```

Вот сюда должен записываться список городов:

```
<div id="cities"></div>
```

Сейчас он в `div` записывается просто через запятую. А нужно, чтобы было в таком виде:

```
<div id="cities">
    <span> Город1 </span>
    <span> Город2 </span>
    <!-- и т.д -->
</div>
```

**Обновление**

Пояснение задачи. В общем начну издалека. Есть список оборудования. Например, ты выбираешь какую-то позицию, и показывается список городов, куда это оборудование отправили, в какой город, точнее. Реализовано это на аяксе, обрабатывается на стороне клиента, и выводится этот список через запятую, в каком-нибудь `span`, а мне нужно, чтоб каждый город был в отдельном `span`.

Comment: да, он и так парсится. выводится в блоке вот в таком виде через запятую. просто мне нужно чтоб было это не через запятую, а как разные объекты. чтоб я мог использовать каждый город отдельно.

Comment: попробуй решить свою задачу через css `span:after { content: ', '; display: inline }` http://jsfiddle.net/Locex1e0/

Comment: @ArkadiyAfonin в вопросе спрашивается про преобразование массива в список `<span>`, а не про добавление запятых между `<span>`.

Comment: @ArkadiyAfonin меня обратный процесс интересует)

Comment: @zagazat так дополненный ответ Qwertiy вас устраивает?

Answer (score 1):

Это же просто массив. Парсишь json джаваскриптом или php (из вопроса не понял, чем тебе надо) и берёшь массив из поля `city`.

> ок. как имея массив строк вывести каждую из них в отдельном span'е?

```
var cities = ["Москва", "Cанкт-Петербург"];

var html = cities.map(function(city) {
  return "<span>" + city.replace(/</g, "&lt;") + "</span>";
}).join(", ");
```

Comment: Вопрос достаточен для ответа. На каком языке нужно распарсить json автор разберётся самостоятельно. Зачем ждать бесполезных уточнений, которые повлияют только на одно слово в ответе?

Comment: Согласен, сформулировал криво. Попробовал по-другому. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @zagazat, ты не знаешь, как имея массив строк вывести каждую из них в отдельном span'е? Тогда так и спроси, а не суй свой json.

Comment: @Qwertiy потому что после уточнений можно бы было дать нормальный (с описанием конкретных действий и примером кода), а не полу-абстрактный ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ок. как имея массив строк вывести каждую из них в отдельном span'е?

Answer (score 0):

Перебираем в цикле весь ответ, и каждый добавляем в конец `#cities`

```
for(var i in res.city){
    $('#cities').append('<span>' + res.city[i] + '</span>');
}
```